# How to use props from connect without having to explicitly write them when rendering component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am using redux/connect to get state and actions creators as props in my component. This, however, causes an error with Typescript when rendering the component as the props i'm receiving via connect are not explicitly written.

Is there a way to get around this without making the types optional or is there something else I am missing?

//FetchData Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { 
    getData, 
    filterMaterial,
    filterSize,
    resetMap
} from "../js/actions/index";

import { MapProperties } from '../types/state';
import { Appstate } from '../js/store';

type DispatchProps = {
    getData: () => void, 
    filterMaterial: (name:string) => void,
    filterSize: (name:string) => void,
    resetMap: () => void
}

type Props = DispatchProps & LinkStateProps

class FetchData extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this)
    }

    handleReset = () => {
        if(this.props.resetMap) this.props.resetMap();
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.getData) this.props.getData()
    }

    render() {        
        return (
         ...
        );
    }
}

type LinkStateProps = {
    geoJSON: MapProperties,
    mapJSON: MapProperties
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: Appstate, props:Props):LinkStateProps => {
    return { 
        geoJSON: state.geoJSON,
        mapJSON: state.mapJSON
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getData, 
    filterMaterial,
    filterSize,
    resetMap
})(FetchData);
```

//App Component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import FetchData from './components/FetchData';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            //error = Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'DispatchProps': getData, filterMaterial, filterSize, resetMap
            <FetchData />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're passing `Props` into your `mapToState` function.

try:

```
- const mapStateToProps = (state: Appstate, props:Props):LinkStateProps => {
+ const mapStateToProps = (state: Appstate):LinkStateProps => {
    return { 
        geoJSON: state.geoJSON,
        mapJSON: state.mapJSON
    };
};
```

The second argument to `mapToState` is an optional `ownProps` argument that is only needed if you need any of the component's "own" props (not connected props) to create the proper mapping from state to props.  Providing `Props` as you did makes TypeScript assume that those props must be provided explicitly when using the component, hence the error you were seeing.

---

Also, you might consider using some built-in features that TypeScript offers to save you from typing things that TypeScript can infer types from automatically.

Consider this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { 
    getData, 
    filterMaterial,
    filterSize,
    resetMap
} from "../js/actions/index";

import { MapProperties } from '../types/state';
import { Appstate } from '../js/store';

const mapStateToProps = (state: Appstate) => ({
  geoJSON: state.geoJSON,
  mapJSON: state.mapJSON
});

const dispatchProps = {
  getData,
  filterMaterial,
  filterSize,
  resetMap
}

// You could do:

// type LinkStateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
// type DispatchProps = typeof dispatchProps;
// type Props = LinkStateProps & DispatchProps;

// or in one line:
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof dispatchProps;

class FetchData extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this)
    }

    handleReset = () => {
        if(this.props.resetMap) this.props.resetMap();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.getData) this.props.getData()
    }

    render() {
        return (
         <p>something</p>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchProps)(FetchData);
```

Creating an object named `dispatchProps` (which you do anyway to supply to `connect`) lets you use Typescript's `typeof` operator to auto-generate the type signature.  And since `mapStateToProps` returns an object, you can use `ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>` to get the type signature of that object.  Combining these two with the '&' operator gives you your `Props` type.  It's essentially a more concise (and less error-prone) way to do the exact same thing you were doing.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, seemed silly, I'm still not used to typescript yet